# Forcibly mark a class in a library of a SDK as Serializable in C#

Tags: c#, class, sdk, serializable

My application uses an SDK (that I have bought recently). Although I have marked my class as serializable, when I want to serialize it, an error occurs:

Type 'FLib.FClass' in Assembly 'IOp.FLib, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyTocken=nul' is not marked as serializable.

How can I forcibly mark FClass as serializable?

Comment: Make you own class with object creating error inside class.  Then make class Iserializable.  See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found is to unassign the events of an object, before serializing it and then reassign them, and assign the events right after the deserialization as well. Something like this:

```
        MemoryStream stream;
        .
        .
        .

        // Serialize
        obj.Event1 -= Obj_Event1;
        obj.Event2 -= Obj_Event2;
        ...
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
        obj.Event1 += Obj_Event1;
        obj.Event2 += Obj_Event2;
        ...

        .
        .
        .

        // Deserialize
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        obj = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        obj.Event1 += Obj_Event1;
        obj.Event2 += Obj_Event2;
        ...
```